# Check for mobile vs desktop

Tags: mobile, pine-script, pine-script-v5

In pine script, is there a way to check if the user is currently on a mobile app so I can set a specific label size depending on form factor?

I tried looking for functions but cant find anything that resolves the form factor to build into my if statements.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not possible.

You can add a user input for the label (or any other drawing) size.